# Concise way to output to file if argument is given, to stdout otherwise

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

I'd like my script to output to stdout unless it gets a filename as an argument.
An obvious way is like so:

```
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
  command_with_output >$1
else
  command_with_output
fi
```

It's pretty ugly and has repetition, so I'd like a more consice way to do it.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
[ -e "$1" ] && outfile=$1 || outfile='&1'
command_with_output >$outfile
```

Edit:
This doesn't change the relevancy of the answers, but I realized after I made the question that `touch "$1" && outfile=$1` is really what I need instead of `[ -e "$1" ] && outfile=$1` since the file may not already exist, and I want to make sure I can write to it or create it, not just that it exists. I'm not changing the question because it would put the answers out of sync.

Comment: I wouldn't normally do that. For users of the script, is it really a gain being able to call your script `./yourscript.sh filename` instead of `./yourscript.sh > filename`? I'd say no, or at least the marginal benefit is normally outweighed by the additional complexity in the interface. The exception to the rule is programs with non-human-readable output (Say, image converter, or wget). Those usually provide an `-o filename` switch where filename can be `-` to say you really want that crap on stdout.

Answer (score 8):

`exec` can be used to redirect the current script's stdout to another file.

```
[ -e "$1" ] && exec > $1
command_with_output
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `$1` as the filename if it was passed, and `/dev/stdout` otherwise (which is a symbolic link to `/proc/self/fd/1` under Linux, and a device node with the same meaning on many other unix variants). E.g. put this at the top of the script:

```
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    filename=$1
else
    filename=/dev/stdout
fi
```

And then redirect the output of every command to `$filename`

Comment: I prefer the [`exec`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42135) method because you can fail early if the output file is not writable.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't take any but file parameters, this will work too:

```
command_with_output > ${1:-/dev/stdout}
```

edit:
Or better yet, since you probably care about errors too:

```
command_with_output &> ${1:-/dev/stdout}
```

Comment: That's the same as @michael-mrozek's except it doesn't check for the existance of `$1` before using it. Which is okay; what I really want is `touch $1 &&...` instead, to make sure I can create/write to the file.

Comment: it's more concise. :)